# Simple eigenvalue and eigenvector of $\{\sin(|i-j|x)\}_{1\le i,j\le5}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}   0&\sin(x)&\sin(2x)&\sin(3x)&\sin(4x)   \\\sin(x)&0&\sin(x)&\sin(2x)&\sin(3x)   \\\sin(2x)&\sin(x)&0&\sin(x)&\sin(2x)   \\\sin(3x)&\sin(2x)&\sin(x)&0&\sin(x)   \\\sin(4x)&\sin(3x)&\sin(2x)&\sin(x)&0   \end{bmatrix}$.

Question 1. (out of 3) of the exercise asks for an **easy** eigenvalue and eigenvector, but after having searched for an hour, tried some Chebichev tricks, I haven't found anything.

Looking at simple cases (n=1,n=2), I didn't see any logical progression either.

By the way : Question 2 is to give its characteristic polynomial, so we are not supposed to use it here I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix is real, symmetric, persymmetric, centrosymmetric, Toeplitz, and traceless. Let $J$ be the flip matrix (zeros except for 1's along the counter-diagonal). [It is straightforward to show that the eigenvectors are either even or odd](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379576901014) (with respect to elements about the middle of the vector). Therefore, there will be 3 even eigenvectors, and 2 odd eigenvectors. The reduced $2\times2$ problem for the odd eigenvectors is
$$ \begin{bmatrix} -\sin4x & \sin x-\sin3x \\ \sin x-\sin3x & -\sin2x \end{bmatrix} v = \lambda v$$
You can straightforwardly find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this $2\times 2$ matrix. You can do a similar thing with the even eigenvectors, but you have a $3x3$ matrix. For the second part of the problem, you can see that the 5th degree characteristic equation should factor into the product of a quadratic and cubic, based on the arguments above. None of this seems like an "easy" answer, so this is probably not the right approach.

Taking a more analytic approach, notice the matrix $M$ is the imaginary part of the discrete Fourier convolution operator of order 5 of a delta function. I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: I don't see where in the [pdf you linked](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379576901014/1-s2.0-0024379576901014-main.pdf?_tid=cc5d3ac8-63a2-11e4-90d2-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1415051339_643196864ac0aaf0d2f56c62852149e1) it is straightforward that the eigenvectors are either even or odd, could you give me the page number ?

Comment: It's on page 279 and 280 of the journal. Basically, using the right sized $J$ matrices, you can express the quadrants of the matrices in terms of just the upper left quadrant. This directly translates to a unitary transformation, decoupling even and odd eigenvectors.